# How to get the number of rows available (unused) in a terminal?

Tags: shell, terminal

I can get the total number of rows and columns with `stty` or `tput`, but how can I get either the number of rows available (not used) or the index/number of the current row/line in bash or any other shell?

Example:

```
$ ls
foo bar baz
$ (cursor is here)
.
.
```

This terminal has 5 rows. The "current row" is 3 and the number of available rows/blank lines after the cursor is 2.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *available (not used)*? Do you mean blank lines below the cursor? It would also be useful to show what you've already researched so far.

Comment: As per this part of your question: "* ... the number of rows available... of the current row ...*": what is your definition of "current"? I.e. isn't that like "the row being processed"? If so, then that is always 1. Must be me who doesn't get it ...

Comment: Anthony Geoghegan: yes, that's what I need. Pierre.Vriens: I've added an example.

Comment: Depends on the terminal, obviously. Nowaday, most people say "terminal" when they mean a "terminal emulator", and most terminal emulators are more or less compatible with [Xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/). Read the escape sequences understood by Xterm. You may also be interested in the [`terminfo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man5/terminfo.5.html) database, and in the [`ncurses`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) library. And anyway, 99.9% of the time the cursor is on the last line of the terminal...

Comment: @AlexP thanks! If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! termios="$(stty -g 2>/dev/null)" 
then
    echo "ERROR: Not running in a terminal"
    exit 1
fi


# Get max rows and columns
maxrows=$(tput lines)
maxcols=$(tput cols)

# Disable ICANON ECHO
stty -icanon -echo

# Get cursor position
tput u7
read -d "R" rowcol

# Revert to original settings
stty "$termios"

# clean up response
rowcol="${rowcol//[^0-9;]/}"
rowcol="${rowcol//;/ }"

printf 'maxrows: %d  maxcols: %d  currow: %d  curcol: %d\n' $maxrows $maxcols ${rowcol[0]} ${rowcol[1]}

exit 0
```